# HTML/PHP/JS issue - onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

So here i am trying to call a function that passes 2 values as parameters (added dynamically using php). The damn thing doesn't seem to work no matter what i try. Can any of you guys point out what i'm doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
// HTML/PHP

$pid = $row['postID'];
$pt = $row['postTitle'];

//There arrays are working great.

<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo "delpost($pid, '$pt')"; ?>">Delete</a> // Does not call delpost

<a href="#" onclick="delpost(<?php echo $pid; ?>)">Delete</a> // BUT if i remove the second parameter, it works! How? 

// JS

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function delpost(id, title) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete" + title + "?")) {
        window.location.href = 'index.php?delpost=' + id;
      }
}

</script>
```

Comment: because of the double quotes try this `<?php echo $pid.',\"'.$pt.'\"'; ?>`

Comment: Yes i have, i made it a little more cleaner 

<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo "delpost($pid, '$pt')"; ?>">Delete</a>

Still doesn't work.

Comment: I copied your code Riqwan, directly from your question, and it's working for me.

Comment: Ok, i just changed $pt = $row['postTitle'] to $pt = $row['postContent] & it works! Now here is the new problem. Why doesn't postTitle work?

postTitle is a varchar(200) whereas postContent is text in the mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes on `"delpost` are wrong. `delpost` is a function so `onclick"<?php echo delpost($pid,$pt); ?>"` should work.

Comment: Its not a syntax error. The function works. But only with text. postTitle is varchar(200) datatype in mySQL. The values are being echo'd, but js doesn't accept it as a valid parameter i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Delete // Does not call delpost Delete // BUT if i remove the second parameter, it works! How?

first delete is not working because when you are passing two value on a function one value is blank that why its not working

```
<?
$pid = 1;
$pt = 2;
//There arrays are working great.
?>

<a href="#" onclick="delpost(<?php echo $pid?>,<?php echo $pt?>)">Delete</a> // Does not call delpost

<a href="#" onclick="delpost(<?php echo $pid; ?>)">Delete</a> // BUT if i remove the second parameter, it works! How? 


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function delpost(id, title) {
    alert(id);
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete" + title + "?")) {
        window.location.href = 'index.php?delpost=' + id;
      }
}

</script>
```

Comment: The other one isn't blank. postTitle is a varchar(200) and it exists. But when i changed to postContent (which is a Text datatype in mySQL), it works. Any reason why postTitle doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="delpost(<?=$pid?>, '<?=$pt?>')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code directly and it worked, but i also have added another way of writing it:

```
<?php

  $pid = 42;
  $pt = 'Awesometitle 2000';
?>

<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo "delpost($pid, '$pt')"; ?>">Delete</a>
<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo 'delpost(' . $pid . ', \'' . $pt . '\');'; ?>">Delete 2</a>


<script>
function delpost(id, title) {
  console.log(id);
  console.log(title);
}
</script>
```

Both variations should print 42 and "Awesometitle 2000" in your console.

Comment: Ok, after checking out your code, i just changed $pt = $row['postTitle'] to $pt = $row['postContent] & it works! Now here is the new problem. Why doesn't postTitle work? postTitle is a varchar(200) whereas postContent is text in the mysql db.

Comment: Try to echo out `$row['postTitle']`. What do you get? You can type `<?php echo '<pre' . print_r($row, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?>` to see everything in the $row-array.

Comment: That works perfectly. I get the value of the post Title.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the output of the title? Or does it work with the title now?